# SyncAdapter on static field warning

Tags: android, android-service, android-context, android-syncadapter

I have this code for my `SyncService`:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

    private static SyncAdapter syncAdapter = null;
    private static final Object syncAdapterLock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        synchronized (syncAdapterLock) {
            if (syncAdapter == null) {
                syncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return syncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

This code I made based on the Android developers page here: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter#CreateSyncAdapterService

The problem is: the `static` on the `SyncAdapter` is complaining:

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static
>   reference to 'SyncAdapter' which has field 'context' pointing to
>   'Context'); this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

But that is how it is in the Android developers page. So, it is right or wrong to it that way? If it is wrong, what would be the correct way?
I couldn't find any info about this particular point...

Comment: have you included the permissions`<service
                android:name="com.example.android.datasync.SyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `Service` extends `Context`. You should not link to context in a static filed which could be a cause of a memory leak (because even when Garbage Collector will destroy the object static link will still be available, and will still hold the context object to not be destroyed).
I think the solution here to remove `static` modifier. Which was probably added by mistake.

Comment: I understand the `Context` problem, but I tough that, since the context used is the aplication context, this case in particular it wouldn't be a problem to use static to make the `SyncAdapter` a singleton.

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't be. It's just - you should not hold context - take it as a best practices. Also, android studio just checks every static links that hold context and warns you.